# not getting expected result while using passport in nodejs for authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport-local

> in server.js :
>
> var User = mongoose.model('User');  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
>        function(username,password,done){
>
> ```
>   User.findOne({username:username}).exec(function(err,user){
>
>       if(user){
>           return done(null,user);
>       } else{
>
>           return done(null,false);
>       }
>
>   });   
>  }
>  ));
>   passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
>
> if(user){
>     done(null,user._id);
> } });
> ```
>
> passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
>
> ```
> User.findOne({_id : id}).exec(function(err,user){
>
>     if(user){
>           return done(null,user);
>       } else{
>
>           return done(null,false);
>       }
> }); });
> ```
>
> express.js :
>
> app.use(session({secret : 'multivision unicorns', resave : false,
>   saveUninitialized : false})); app.use(passport.initialize());
>   app.use(passport.session());
>
> routes.js :
>
> app.post('/login', function(req,resp,next){
>
> ```
> console.log("hitting /login call in routes");
>
> var auth = passport.authenticate('local', function(err,user){
>
>
>     console.log("Calling auth function");
>     console.log("User data : " + user);
>
>     if(err) {return next(err);}
>
>     if(!user){
>         resp.send({success : false});
>     }
>
>     req.logIn(user, function(err){
>         if(err) { return next(err);}
>
>         resp.send({success:true, user:user});
>     })
> });
>
> auth(req,resp,next);
>  });
> ```
>
> in controller :
>
> angular.module('app').controller('navbarCtrl', function($scope,$http){
>
> ```
> $scope.signIn = function(username,password){
>
>     console.log("I am trying to login to website");
>
>     $http.post('/login',{username:username}).then(function(response){
>
>        if(response.data.success){
>            console.log('logged in to webiste buddy!!!');
>        } 
>        else{
>            console.log("Unable to login DUDE!!!!");
>        }
>     });
> }
>      });
> ```
>
> terminal Output :
>
> > hitting /login call in routes  Calling auth function  **User data : false** (User data is always false even though I tried with the existing
> >     user data in DB)
> >     POST /login 200 29.125 ms - 17

Comment: of course it is not, passport.authenticate function takes err,done as arguments (not err, user) , and the req contains the posted arguments, so req.username will be your username

Comment: changed according to ur suggestion, it's not working

Comment: what is not working? please use console.log and try to debug what function gets hits and not

Comment: Also what is the expected result? what is the error message you get? We can not help if you are not clear about those things

Comment: hitting /login call in routes Calling auth function User data : false (User data is always false even though I tried with the existing user data in DB) POST /login 200 29.125 ms - 17

Comment: Use this as an example : https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example